# ESP32 Analog to Digital ADC

Tags: sensors, esp32, adc

I have a humidity analog sensor that I am trying to read. The sensor outputs a 4-20 mA signal. I converted it into a 0 - 3.3V potential with a 165 Ohm resistor.

When I measure the voltage across the resistors with a multimeter, I get the correct values. I get a voltage of around 2.9V which corresponds to about 87 % humidity which seems to be correct.

However the values of ADC are haywire. I get values between 2500 to 4095, which correspond to between 61 % and 100 % humidity. The sensor is quite accurate so its not a problem with the sensor. I am using ADC on pin 25.

My circuit is shown as an attachment. I have also attached the values of ADC measured.

[image]

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
// Potentiometer is connected to GPIO 34 (Analog ADC1_CH6) 
const int Pin = GPIO_NUM_34;
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(Pin, ANALOG);
  delay(1000);
  analogSetAttenuation(ADC_11db);
}
    
void loop() {
  int data = analogRead(Pin);
  double vol = (data * 3.3) / 4095;
  Serial.print(data);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(vol);
  Serial.print("\n");
    
  delay(300);
}
```

Comment: How about posting the code which initializes and reads the ADC?

Comment: Please edit the original question, comments don't preserve formatting :)

Comment: Where is the power connection to the ESP32? Why is there a resistor in the ground line? It makes the ESP32's ground change depending on how much current the sensor pulls.

Comment: this is a rough sketch. there is no resistor in the gnd line. it was a mistake.